# Restart doesn't work on Ubuntu 12.04 but shutdown

Tags: 12.04, laptop, vaio, restart

I'm a newbie to Linux and Ubuntu but I installed it as the second OS (after Win7) on my Sony Vaio netbook. Everything's working fine except for Ubuntu doesn't restart properly. Shutting down is working well but when doing a restart it looks like it is restarting but then it shows a black screen and fails to re-boot. What I have to do is force its shutdown by holding the power button.
I remember having experienced a similar problem with an earlier Ubuntu version running on completely different hardware, too.

Please, help me resolve it.
Regards
Ralf

Comment: Are you dual-booting, with Windows?  Was Windows previously installed on the netbook?

Comment: Yes, I'm dual-booting with Windows 7. Yes, Windows was installed as the first OS on that Sony Vaio. On a Lenovo notebook there is also a problem but with shutting down (seems to have shut down but the fans are still working) but restarting is working fine. It's a dual boot as well.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue while 12.04 was in beta. Its gone now though. My recommendation is to make sure you install the latest kernel update (i.e. make sure your system is 100% up-to-date) and try reinstalling your video drivers (if they are proprietary or otherwise self-installed). I've had issues with booting when I don't reinstall my ATI drivers after a kernel update, though I'm pretty sure they wouldn't cause an issue with shutting down.

If that doesn't work, you may want to look to see if there's anything in the system logs, though I'm not entirely sure which ones would be applicable.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a start up usb drive it has the same shut down issues in Unity. After installing gnome fall-back it would shut down using this. 
Plus I had shut down issues in my Acer netbook the gnome interface helped in the 11.0 version but the 12.0 versions shut down better after installing the newest updates the updates cleared up shut down issues in the older versions as well. I have wubi installed versions in my Toshiba laptop as well do your updates they seem to iron out a lot of issues.